# Prove the computational formula of Anderson-Darling test statistic.

Tags: statistics

The Anderson-Darling test statistic is defined as

$$n\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(F_n(x) - F(x))^2}{F(x)(1 - F(x))}dF(x)$$

and there is a computational formula

$$A^2 = -n - S$$

where

$$S = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{n}\left(\ln F(Y_k) + \ln(1 - F(Y_{n+1-k}))\right)$$

$F_n(x)$ is the empirical distribution function and $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution to which we are comparing the sample. $Y_k$ is the $k^\text{th}$ ranked element in the sample.

Many books or journals I found all give these two formulas but don't give the reason and derivations.

I tried to divide the integral into sub-intervals like $[Y_i, Y_{i+1}]$ to prove it, but I failed. So I want to how to prove it. Thanks!!

Comment: Interesting question.  I may see if I can do something with it.

Answer (score 2):

Anderson and Darling ([1954, pp.767--768](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2281537?uid=3739656&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104341865283)) explain the derivation as such:

[image]

where (2) is:

[image]

Comment: Could you email this journal to me? I want more details.

Comment: Your e-mail isn't listed; mine is. E-mail me offline, please. Thanks.

Comment: Avraham, is it possible to access this journal? Thanks

Comment: @albert, please e-mail me offline.